# React Select - setState of prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I am trying to set the state of my brandSelect prop in ReactJS using [React Select](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select) however I am confused to how this can be done?

Here is my current code:

```
class VehicleSelect extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { brandSelect: ""};

  }
  render() {
    var options = [
    { value: 'Volkswagen', label: 'Volkswagen' },
    { value: 'Seat', label: 'Seat' }
    ];


    return (
      <Select
          name="form-field-name"
          value={this.state.brandSelect}
          options={options}
          placeholder="Select a brand"
          searchable={false}
          onChange={}
      />
    )
  }
};
```

When the option is selected I want the state to be set as the option chosen.

Does anybody know how this is done with React Select as the documentation doesn't really cover this? So far I have tried making a function with a set state attached to the onChange prop however this didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

In react 16.8+ the implementation should look like this using React hooks:

> [Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) are a new addition in React 16.8

```
function VehicleSelect() {

  const options = [
    { value: 'volkswagen', label: 'Volkswagen' },
    { value: 'seat', label: 'Seat' }
  ];

  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState({ value: 'volkswagen', label: 'Volkswagen' });

  const [handleChange] = useState(() => {
    return () => {
      setSelectedOption(selectedOption);
    };
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Select
        name="form-field-name"
        placeholder="Select a brand"
        searchable={false}
        value={selectedOption}
        onChange={handleChange}
        options={options}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: The handleChange uses the current selected value as an input, the value won't change.

Answer (score 0):

You can try do add `_onChange` handler to your component, that will handle changes form `<Select />` component.

```
class VehicleSelect extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { brandSelect: ""};

  }

  _onChange(value) {
    //console.log(value) - just to see what we recive from <Select />
    this.setState({brandSelect: value});
  }

  render() {
    var options = [
    { value: 'Volkswagen', label: 'Volkswagen' },
    { value: 'Seat', label: 'Seat' }
    ];


    return (
      <Select
          name="form-field-name"
          value={this.state.brandSelect}
          options={options}
          placeholder="Select a brand"
          searchable={false}
          onChange={this._onChange.bind(this)}
      />
    )
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class VehicleSelect extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        brandSelect: ""
      };

    }
    onSelectChanged(value) {
      this.setState({
        brandSelect: value
      });
    }
    render() {
        var options = [{
          value: 'Volkswagen',
          label: 'Volkswagen'
        }, {
          value: 'Seat',
          label: 'Seat'
        }];

        <Select
       name="form-field-name"
       value={this.state.brandSelect}
       options={options}
       placeholder="Select a brand"
       searchable={false}
       onChange={this.onSelectChanged.bind(this)}
       />
```

You need an `onChange` event handler. Pass in an argument to the event handler function which in this case will be the selected value of the `Select` input and then **Set the State** of the `brandSelect` with the selected value.

Answer (score 0):

I used this in my code to work with Selector:

```
class VehicleSelect extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { brandSelect: ""};

  }

  onChange(event) {
    this.setState({brandSelect: event.target.value}); // important
  }

  render() {
    var options = [
    { value: 'Volkswagen', label: 'Volkswagen' },
    { value: 'Seat', label: 'Seat' }
    ];


    return (
      <Select
          name="form-field-name"
          value={this.state.brandSelect}
          options={options}
          placeholder="Select a brand"
          searchable={false}
          onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)}
      />
    )
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const Layout = (props: any) => {

//Row First
const [rows, setRow] = useState({
    rowFirst: "",
    columnFirst: "",
    columnSecond: 0
});

const handleChangeRowFirst = (e: { target: { name: any; value: any; }; }) => {


    setRow({ ...rows, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

    console.log("row", rows);

    props.dispatch({
        type: "setRow",
        payload: rows
    });

};

const onSubmitForm = (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!rows.rowFirst) {
        alert("rowFirst is empty.")
    }
    else if (!rows.columnFirst) {
        alert("columnFirst or rowFirst is empty.")
    }
    else if (!rows.columnSecond) {
        alert("columnSecond is empty.")
    }
}



return (
    <>
        <Grid container className="containerMatrix">
            <form onSubmit={onSubmitForm} className="formMatrix">
                <Grid item xs={6} md={5}>
                    <Box id="test" className="martixNum">
                        <Typography variant="h5" gutterBottom className="nameColMatrix">
                            Enter Numbers First Matrix
                        </Typography>

                        <Box className="martixFirst">
                            <TextField
                                type="number"
                                InputProps={{
                                    inputProps: {
                                        max: 99, min: 0
                                    }
                                }}
                                label="Row" onChange={handleChangeRowFirst} name="rowFirst" id="num1" value={rows.rowFirst}
                            />
                            <TextField
                                type="number"
                                InputProps={{
                                    inputProps: {
                                        max: 99, min: 0
                                    }
                                }}
                                label="Column" onChange={handleChangeRowFirst} name="columnFirst" id="num2" value={rows.columnFirst}
                            />
                        </Box>
                    </Box>
                </Grid>

                <Grid item xs={6} md={5}>
                    <Box id="test" className="martixNum">
                        <Typography variant="h5" gutterBottom className="nameColMatrix">
                            Enter Numbers Second Matrix
                        </Typography>
                        <Box className="martixFirst">
                            <TextField
                                type="number"
                                InputProps={{
                                    inputProps: {
                                        max: 99, min: 0
                                    }
                                }}
                                label="Row" onChange={handleChangeRowFirst} name="columnFirst" id="num3" value={rows.columnFirst}
                            />

                            <TextField
                                type="number"
                                InputProps={{
                                    inputProps: {
                                        max: 99, min: 0
                                    }
                                }}
                                label="Column" onChange={handleChangeRowFirst} name="columnSecond" id="num4"
                            />
                        </Box>

                    </Box>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={6} md={5}>
                    <Box>
                        <Button variant="contained" color="primary" type="submit">
                            Primary
                        </Button>
                    </Box>
                </Grid>
            </form>
        </Grid>
    </>
)
}
```

Comment: Please explain your solution. Answers which do not have an explanation and are only code get flagged as low effort.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.